# Problem loading sld raster style in Geoserver 2.15.1

Tags: geoserver

When I try to load mi sld style to a hillshade raster (tif format) it gives me the folllowing message:

line 21: cvc-complex-type.2.1:the element 'sld: normalize' must not have any characters or any [child] element information elements, because the type content type is empty.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.0.0" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <UserLayer>
    <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
      <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
    </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>hill_22</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
            <sld:Opacity>0.2</sld:Opacity>
            <sld:ChannelSelection>
              <sld:GrayChannel>
                <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
                <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                  <sld:Normalize>
                    <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
                    <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">1</sld:VendorOption>
                    <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">181</sld:VendorOption>
                  </sld:Normalize>
                </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
              </sld:GrayChannel>
            </sld:ChannelSelection>
            <sld:ColorMap>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="0" color="#000000"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="255" color="#ffffff"/>
            </sld:ColorMap>
          </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </UserLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because the GeoServer validator uses the OGC schema to validate the SLD, while specifying optional `VendorOptions` is not part of the standard. So as you know better than the computer you can ignore it and press apply and all will be fine.

If it really bothers you, you can submit a PR to update the schema used to accept this change.

Comment: Thank you for the information Ian. The thing is that when I visualize the layer, it appears with pink-red colours instead of white....